# How to Fix the TComboBox Ctl3D Property Bug?

Tags: delphi, interface, combobox, delphi-2006

This is an image from a `TForm` where I have a `TEdit` at top and a `TComboBox` at down.

[image]

As you can see, the TEdit does not have the classic 3D border of the Windows controls default theme. That's because I set the `Ctl3D property` of that component to `False`. Then you see that the TComboBox has it's normal 3D border, but in this case I also set the `Ctl3D property` of that component to `False`, but it continues to show the 3D border.

It seems to be a Delphi bug at development level. How could I fix that at code?

---

After testing RRUZ answer, `BevelKind=bkFlat`, this came:

[image]

I do not know why it was so different... and bizarre. :-/

Comment: Other component packages that brings ComboBox variations corrects this but then we can't set the border color to black like those TEdits

Comment: Try setting the BevelKind property of the ComboBox to `bkFlat`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can remove the 3D border setting the [`BevelKind`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.BevelKind) property of the [`TComboBox`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Vcl.StdCtrls.TComboBox) to `bkFlat`.

[image]

Comment: I put the result in the question. I don't know why but it was far from your Delphi. :(

Answer (score 1):

I Found it:

We have to set:

`BevelInner` to `bvNone` ;

`BevelKind` to `bkFlat` ;

`BevelOuter` to `bvSpace` .

Answer (score 0):

this is best way which support `BidiMode` and resize; and can fill border with client color:

```
TTestComboBox=class(TComboBox)
protected
  procedure WMPaint(var Msg: TMessage); message WM_Paint;
End;

Procedure TTestComboBox.WMPaint(var Msg: TMessage);
var MCanvas: TControlCanvas;
    R: TRect;
Begin
  inherited;
  MCanvas:=TControlCanvas.Create;
  Try
    MCanvas.Control:=Self;
    With MCanvas do begin
      R:=ClientRect;
      Brush.Style:= bsClear;
      Pen.Color:= Color;
      Pen.Width:= 3;
      if BiDiMode in [bdRightToLeft, bdRightToLeftNoAlign] then begin
        if Style = csSimple then                   //remove border and space
          Rectangle(1, 1, R.Width - 1, R.Height-1) else Rectangle(-1, 1, R.Width, R.Height-1);
        if Style in [csDropDown, csOwnerDrawFixed, csOwnerDrawVariable] then begin
          Pen.Width:= 5;                           //remove space btw editor and button
          MoveTo(18, 0);
          LineTo(18, R.Height-1);
        end;
      end else begin
        if Style = csSimple then
          Rectangle(1, 1, r.Width - 1, R.Height-1) else Rectangle(1, 1, r.Width + 1, R.Height-1);
        if Style in [csDropDown, csOwnerDrawFixed, csOwnerDrawVariable] then begin
          Pen.Width:= 5;
          MoveTo(R.Width - 18, 0);
          LineTo(R.Width - 18, R.Height-1);
        end;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    MCanvas.Free;
  End;
End;
```